# Searching secured/gated content with Solr

Tags: security, search, lucene, solr

Does anything exist within Solr/Lucene for securing/gating content based on some kind of security mechanism?  I'm considering Solr as an enterprise search alternative to the Google Mini/Google Search Appliance, but I will need support for secured content which the Google options do provide.  Does anyone have any experience/suggestions on how to do this with Solr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way to solve this, in my experience, is to index security information (ACL:s and deny-ACL:s or similar), and then do filter queries on it. In short, this requires:

1. Your connector must be able to extract security information
2. Your client/search GUI must be able to look up the current users authorities

This solution assumes that you have some sort of middleware that handles user request, and builds query parameters from them. If you need to let your users interact with Solr directly, [look here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrSecurity).

Comment: For a good discussion on this topic - see http://www.searchtechnologies.com/search-engine-security.html